# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'freetype' in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, freetype

I'm using a docker container with minimal packages installed. I installed `opencv-contrib-python` using `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python` and it installed the latest build `4.1.025` and have verified that it was running and my program was ok with it. However, now I need the `freetype` module but when I try:

```
import cv2 as cv
ft = cv.freetype.createFreeType2()
```

It throws the `AttributeError` as in the title. I tried reinstalling different versions namely: `4.0.0.21, 4.0.1.23, 4.0.1.24, 4.1.0.25` to no avail. I am using the headless version mainly(since I'm using docker and I don't need any gui functionality). Another thing I found out was not all the modules can be imported I have tried (ccalib, tracking, sfm, xobjdetect etc) and these modules throw the same error. Does this mean that some modules are not available through the `pip3` installation? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty late to this issue, but I hope this helps someone.

I've added links to an easy to follow guide at the bottom.

Here are the essential steps, you'd need to follow:

- Install CMake & Git (if you haven't already)
- In a folder git vcpkg (git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git)
- Install freetype and harfbuzz using vcpkg commandline

  - `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`
  - `vcpkg install freetype:x64-windows`
  - `vcpkg install harfbuzz:x64-windows`
- Locate vcpkg.cmake file and note down its path
- Ensure C++ build tools are installed in Visual Studio 19
- Download and extract OpenCV & OpenCV contrib
- Create a empty dir called "build" inside the extracted OpenCV
- Modify CMakeLists.txt inside freetype module folder in opencv-contrib ([Link](https://gist.github.com/UnaNancyOwen/14c72a3f10a46d41c359ab6ea307a1d2#file-readme-md))
- Modify and run the following command:

  - `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" 
    -B D:\code\downloads\opencv-4.3.0\build 
    -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON 
    -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON 
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=yes 
    -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=D:\anaconda3\python.exe 
    -D OPENCV_SKIP_PYTHON_LOADER=ON 
    -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=D:\anaconda3\libs\python36.lib 
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=D:\code\downloads\opencv_contrib-4.3.0\modules 
    -D OPEN_CV_FORCE_PYTHON_LIBS=yes 
    -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\code\downloads\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake`
- Use CMake GUI to make changes referenced at this link ([LINK](https://github.com/BabaGodPikin/Build-OpenCv-for-Python-with-Extra-Modules-Windows-10))
- Once necessary changes are made, click Configure and Generate.
- Building DEBUG & RELEASE versions using Visual Studio 19
- Test the installation by importing cv2.freetype from the environment you setup.

There's a comprehensive written guide over here:

- https://github.com/BabaGodPikin/Build-OpenCv-for-Python-with-Extra-Modules-Windows-10

Also, I've made a video inspired by the same tutorial, which can be found here:

- https://youtu.be/9YUDx3qzKwY

I would recommend watching the video and keeping this guide open on the side.

Cheers!